# Prove that an abelian group of order $pq$, with $(p, q) = 1$ is cyclic if it contains elements of order $p$ and $q$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be an abelian group of order $pq$, with $\gcd(p, q) = 1$.

Assume there exists
$a, b \in G$ such that $|a| = p, |b| = q$.  Prove that $G$ is cyclic.

Comment: i need help, i do not know as start

Comment: $ab?{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: i do not understand you

Comment: obviously is gcd( p, q) = 1

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown  How did you answer that and still meet the minimum character requirement?

Comment: The clue by Lord is the best: what is the order of $\;ab\;$ ? There you go...

Comment: I do not know, it's something very general.

Comment: @Batominovski you can get the answer by following this recipe: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28795/possibility-to-access-the-code-of-peoples-comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $H=\langle a \rangle $ and $K=\langle b \rangle$.
Note that $H\cap K=1$.
By product formula, $|HK|=|H||K|=pq=|G|$. Hence $G=HK$.
Since $H$ and $K$ are both normal subgroups of $G$, $G\cong H\times K\cong \Bbb{Z}_p\times \Bbb{Z}_q$.
Since $p$ and $q$ are relatively prime, $G\cong \Bbb{Z}_{pq}$ and hence $G$ is cyclic.

Comment: Yeah, your second suggestion is way easier, because it requires zero knowledge of internal direct product business and $G$ is abelian, so computing the order of $ab$ is a snap.

Comment: How come that the divisors of $pq$ are only $1,p,q,pq$  when you only know that $\gcd(p,q)$=1? Take for instance $p=8$   and $q=9$.

Comment: @Traveler Yeah you are right. I here assumed that $p$ and $q$ are both prime numbers.